# Error: Service incorrectly implements interface

Tags: typescript

I am implementing an interface in `angular service`. One of my method returns a `observable array`, I want to define that signature in the interface. This is how I am trying to do it:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

export interface IItemStore<T> {
    getItems: Observable<Array<T>>;
}

@Injectable
export class ItemStore implements IItemStore<Item>{
    items: Observable<Array<Item>>;
    getItems(): Observable<Array<Item>>{
      return items;
    }
}
```

This is the error that I get:

```
class `ItemStore` incorrectly implements interface `IItemStore<Item>`. Types of `getItems` are incompatible. Types of property `() => Observable<Item[]>` is not assignable to type `Observable<Item>`. Property `_isScalar` is missing in type `() => Observable<Item[]>`.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because in your interface you declared `getItems` as a field, not a class method. Change it to `getItems()` and it will work just fine. ;)
Furthermore, in the code you provided you are missing `this` keyword before the `items` field in your function.

PS: If this is Angular2 code please note that you should use `@Injectable()` as a function invoke.

Full code solution:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

export interface IItemStore<T> {
    getItems(): Observable<Array<T>>;
}

class Item {}

@Injectable()
export class ItemStore implements IItemStore<Item> {
    items: Observable<Array<Item>>;
    getItems(): Observable<Array<Item>>{
      return this.items;
    }
}
```